# How to reboot a frozen linux unit

Tags: linux, reboot, freeze

There is a PROD unit with Mindspeed c2000 and Linux(3.2.54) on it. It offers many services like SSH, LAN(connecting to back-end), 3G etc. At certain times the unit goes into freeze mode and no way to access it via 3G or LAN or SSH. Is there any way to initiate a reboot of this unit itself, by detecting the hung state? Problem is, it can go to hung state any time and there is no definite checks I can add to determine it before-hand.

Comment: First step is to find out what exactly hangs. So get console access (via a serial port, or whatever the "unit" has) during a hang and/or look at the error messages that appear before the hang. In theory, you can run a watchdog process, or use a watchdog timer in the kernel, but if the "hang" is of a nature where these won't work, that won't help.

Comment: Was not successful in identifying whats that exactly causing the hung state. Sample crash log collected via serial port is here: https://filebin.net/bi0g4zlw06mjclne/dlc200_20crash.txt?t=vcqyp0z7

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/741768/reboot-on-hardware-freeze

Comment: Um, you have plenty of kernel stacktraces, most caused by CPU 0 hang. First guess is a serious hardware problem. Second guess is corrupted firmware, so try re-installing the system. Don't continue using this unit as it is. (And if you already have those, why on earth did you think it's not relevant to the question? This should have been included right from the start.)

Comment: And the `bad eraseblocks` at the beginning indicate that your flash is probably gone, too. You can invest a lot of time trying to find out what's wrong, or just buy a new unit.

Comment: Does not look like the firmware corruption issue, tried with different firmwares and few units as well(issue not in juts 1 unit).